# Disable bounce/scroll on embedded vimeo-player

Tags: ios, iframe, webview, bounce, vimeo-player

[image: Example what happens on touch + move up]

*When touch + move up, the webview bounces (the white area at the bottom shows) (the close button is not affected because its not in the webview)*

I have problems disable bounce/scroll when opening a embedded Vimeo player inside a webview. The player is embeded in an iframe - which makes it an iframe inside an iframe.

I have successfully disabled scroll and bounce for the webview and the first iframe, I use this native code

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {

        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

        [[subview scrollView] setScrollEnabled: NO];


    }
```

And for the first webview and the iframe i use javascript

```
addLoadEvent(function () {
  document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

Problem this works on the webview and first iframe but not on the embedded vimeo iframe.

Answer (score 0):

With that include this might work.

```
webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Also as the video is inside a frame and the frame inside Webview then the video frame is a subview of frame and not webview. You should try to search for class in frame and disable scrol. :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply! webView.scrollView you mean? Doesn't work. I found out the webView missing subviews when trying to iterate it. So I guess I must go do this at some other level? How do I access the vimeo iframe's properties?

Comment: If you are just loading an online video to the iframe the you cant access it as the settings are set by video server (This case Vimeo).... If you download and then load or load a local video then just set those two lines for webview (scroll view for you) and it should work.... and also for subviews.....

Comment: No I can't download the videos, they must be streamed. Maybe there is some native way to inject the touchmove javascript code into the iframe? I guess the cross domain rules will stop me from doing that with javascript from the container document.

Comment: Yes, cross domain rules will stop it (Vimeo may not enable it either)... can you post a screenshot.. to see if I can help...